# Vowels aren't filtered out

Tags: javascript

Just learning basics of JavaScript and trying to get rid off vowels from a string:

```
function disemvowel(str) {
  let no_vowels = '';
  for (let a = 0; a < str.length; a++) {
    if (str[a] !== 'a' || str[a] !== 'A' || str[a] !== 'i' ||
        str[a] !== 'I' || str[a] !== 'o' || str[a] !== 'O' ||
        str[a] !== 'u' || str[a] !== 'U' || str[a] !== 'e' ||
                                              str[a] !== 'E') {
      // if none of the above is in the index add it to no_vowels
      no_vowels += str[a];
   }
  }
  return no_vowels;
}
```

String is unchanged. Why ?

Comment: if something is not equal to a *or* not equal to b, it can be equal to a or b quite happily

Comment: This is something a lot of people struggle with at first. :-) What your code says is "If x is not 'a' OR x is not 'b' OR ..." That's always true, because if it's "a" then it's not "b" and if it's "b" then it's not "a". You want AND (`&&`), not OR.

Comment: Oh ... I need to swap || for && right ?

Comment: `!(a || b) = !a && !b`

Comment: Haha ... I'm such a dum***s. Thank you.

Comment: Trust me, **lots** of people do this. :-)